# Backbone: Collection Won't Reset

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fetch, reset

I'm trying to `.reset()` to clear my `collection` before calling `.fetch()` on it to retrieve new data for that page.

But for some reason my `collection` isn't being resetted and fetching the new data when I navigate to another page. It only resets the collection and gets the new data when I manually reload the page.

```
class ProjectPostItemsView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['project_post_items.ejs']
  posts_item_views: []

  initialize: ->
    super()
    @listenTo( @collection, 'add', @displayPostItem )
    @collection.reset().fetch(add: true)

  displayPostItem: (project) ->
    view = new ProjectPostItemView(model: project)
    @posts_item_views.push( view.on('render', =>
      @$('.post-items').append(view.$('>'))) )

  render: (options) ->
    super(options)
```

I'm very new to Backbone so I'm not sure if I'm handling this correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling reset before your fetch, a better way to do this would be to use:

```
 collection.fetch({reset: true});
```

As per the Backbonejs docs,
*"When the model data returns from the server, it uses set to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass {reset: true}, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) reset."*
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: Oh, of course! Much better answer than mine. Well done :)

Comment: Thanks! If you think so why not give me and upvote? :)

Comment: @slinhart What about `add: true` that's already being passed to the `fetch()` method?

Comment: If you want to trigger an add event for each model in the collection do collection.fetch({reset: true, add: true});
Again, check out the docs, all this info is there. Cheers

Comment: @slinhart I've tried this, when I go to my page it loads the correct collection, but when I navigate to another page it loads the same collection and I get this error: `Uncaught Error: Duplicate id: can't add the same model to a collection twice`. It's only until I manually refresh that it returns the correct collection.

Comment: I'm not sure without viewing your code. But I also wonder why you are trying to fetch the collection when going to a new page. The first thing that comes to mind is something like:
if(!collection.length) collection.fetch();
Not sure if this is relevant to your particular issue though.

Comment: @slinhart Each page has its own collection of unique posts that I'm trying to load. That's what I'm trying to fetch, like so: 1. Go to page \\ 2. Empty collection \\ 3. Fetch collection. Is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82704/discussion-between-slinhart-and-realph).

Answer (score 1):

A collection's `reset` function doens't return the collection object, so you can't chain `reset` and `fetch`. Change the last line of the `initialize` function to two lines:

```
@collection.reset()
@collection.fetch()
```

Side note: there's no reason to pass `{add: true}` to `fetch`. Any new models entering the collection will automatically trigger the "add" event you're listening for.